# Apache Jackrabbit 2.10.1.rar version does not deploy in wildfly 9.0.1

Tags: java, apache, wildfly, jackrabbit, jca

I tried to deploy Apache Jackrabbit-2.10.1.rar on Wildfly 9.0.1 but i get an exception:

> org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056:
>
> > Description: A ResourceAdapter must implement a \\"public boolean equals(Object)\\" method.
> >     Code: org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAResourceAdapter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.deployment%2Fhtml%2Fapplicationserversetup%2Fjboss.html

It says:

Due to an issue with validation when deploying Jackrabbit on JBoss ( see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-3241), the archive-validation should be disabled within the JCA subsystem in /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml as a workaround:

```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
   <archive-validation enabled="false" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
```